# C# period('.') being added to file path when entered via command line

Tags: c#, file-io, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program for a homework assignment that is meant to take two program arguments from the command line. The first is a word to search for in a text file, the second is the file path of the file to be searched. The program looks for the word and if it finds it, prints which number the word is in the file(i.e. word number 10).

The problem is that when I enter the two arguments:

```
homework "C:\\Users\\louiz\\source\\repos\\File and exception hw\\File and 
exception hw\\bin\\Debug\\File_for_homework_11_17"
```

I get an error that the file could not be found. The error message in Visual Studio seems to indicate that there is a period at the end of the file path for some reason.

[image]

This period is not part of the text I entered (see below)

[image]

Below is my code. It is fairly simple at this point I intend to add a file not found exception handler and a message to print if the searched word is not found. But I want to make sure I can read the file first. I know that having these operations done via command line is likely not the simplest method, but it is what the assignment requires. I just can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        string lookFor = args[0];
        int count = 0;

        StreamReader f = new StreamReader(args[1]);

        while((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] strings = line.Split(new char[]{' '});
            if (strings[count] == lookFor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was word number {1} in the file.", lookFor, count);
            }

            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you are using the wrong slashes there. Also the point belongs to the "Exception Message Printout" part, not the actuall fielpath.

Comment: The backshash should only be escaped (`\\ `) in a string literal in code, not on the command line. Try `homework c:\Users\louiz...`

Comment: Are you sure that the file doesn't have any extention, like `.txt`? If it does, you need to provide that too (Explorer may not be showing the extension, but you still need to provide it).

Comment: Is `File_for_homework_11_17` part of your VS solution? Get its properties and tell us what the Copy To Output value is.

Answer (score 0):

The period belongs to the exception message, your string is printed in single quotes within this message.

So the problem is indeed that the file could not be found. Check if it really exists. Maybe the file extension is missing? Any spelling mistake?

Furthermore you don't need the double slashes but they don't hurt.

Comment: Which doesn´t really solve the problem. In fact OP only *supposes* that the dot is related to the issue, whuch it is not.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's right. Added some more details